# can't source script files linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, maven

when installing a java/maven environment on fedora20 , I made the following steps:

Step 1) I created a directory /usr/local/xxx

Step 2) I put into my directory a jdk,maven and some other stuff

/usr/local/xxx/jdk

/usr/local/xxx/maven

Step 3) I edited my .bash_profile to export variables java_home and maven_home, here is the content :

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
JAVA_HOME='/usr/local/xxx/jdk/jdk1.7.0_79'
M2_HOME='/usr/local/xxx/apache-maven-3.3.3'

export JAVA_HOME
export M2_HOME
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2:$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Step 4) source  ~/.bash_profile

then echo $JAVA_HOME and echo $M2_HOME, my variables are well exported

Step 5) I moved the jdk and maven to /opt and updated ~/.bash_profile (replace /usr/local/xxx with /opt)

Step 6) I renamed /usr/local/xxx to /usr/local/yyy

Here is the problem : after last two steps when i try to source ~/.bash_profile or any other script file I get the following message : bash /home/myUserName is a directory.

and the sourcing doesn't work.

What can be the origin of this problem ? and how to get sourcing work again to export my ~/.bash_profile updates ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a problem with your $PATH content.

Check `which bash` and have a look to the given directory, because if this problem occurs with all your scripts, that may be because bash cannot be reached.

Comment: thanks for your answer , didn't try it yet but I'll make a feed back once done